# How to access media from Google Play Music?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I get a list of entries (on device as well as offline) using the content provider URI **content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/audio** with the following code:

```
String[] proj = { MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID };
Uri gMusicUri = Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.music.MusicContent/audio");
Ln.d("onCreate(): XX gMusicUri = %s", gMusicUri);
Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(gMusicUri, proj, null, null, null);
if (cursor == null) {
    // query failed, handle error.
    Ln.w("onCreate(): XX cursor is null, query failed");
} else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // no media on the device
    Ln.w("onCreate(): XX cursor cannot move to 1st element, no media on device");
} else {
    int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
    int titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
    int artistColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
    do {
       long id = cursor.getLong(idColumn);
       String title = cursor.getString(titleColumn);
       String artist = cursor.getString(artistColumn);
       // ...process entry...
        Ln.i("onCreate(): XX id = %d, title = %s, artist = %s", id, title, artist);
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

I would need to stream the media and wonder if it is possible at all?!

Comment: Kokic how can we get the path of file through the content uri i have facing the problem that it have returning me the the following exception Invalid column _data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My [unofficial Google Music api](https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API) does this by using the same call the web site does:  at the moment, this is `https://play.google.com/music/play`. `songid` is the relevant parameter. The response schema is [here](https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API/blob/26f6efb193aec4ff3fdf1f26c705eff3e1b3c303/gmusicapi/protocol.py#L647).

If you're on Android, you'll be able to simplify the auth process by using `AccountManager` and the Google Music `sj` service.

Here's another, possibly easier, way: http://dpogue.ca/gmusic.html. I didn't write this, so I'm not sure if it's up to date.

If you end up figuring out how to stream from the that uri instead, please create an answer - I'd be curious to know!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will check it out asap.

Comment: After a while, I tried a few things and managed to authenticate using android AccountManager as well as to use loadalltracks and play service ends. Unfortunately, the obtained stream url is being rejected (403).

Comment: I'm not sure if Darryl's site is up to date. . .are you including the `X-Device-ID` header?